# provide case- insensitive search of DB (core data)

Tags: iphone, case-sensitive

I am a starter in iPhone. I wanted to do case-insensitive search. Database helper used: `Core Data`.

Following is my code:

```
   -(WebAttendee *) FindAttendeeBy:(NSString *) badgeID_
    {

        AppDelegate_Shared *delegate1 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


        badgeID_=[badgeID_ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];

        badgeID_=[badgeID_ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];

        self.managedObjectContext = delegate1.managedObjectContext;

        return (WebAttendee *)[self FetchManagedObject:@"WebAttendee" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@ "Barcode LIKE [c] %@",badgeID_ ]];


    }
    -(NSManagedObject *)FetchManagedObject:(NSString *)entity_:(NSString *)predicate_
        {

            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity_ inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [request setEntity:entity];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate_];
            [request setPredicate:predicate];

            NSError *error = nil;

//--------------------------crashes at this step---------------------------------           
            mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

            NSLog(@"FetchResult=%@",mutableFetchResults);
            [request release];
            if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
                // Handle the error.
            }

            if([mutableFetchResults count]!=0)
            return [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
            else {
                return nil;
            }

        }

but i am getting the following error:

    2012-07-05 12:58:52.917 SpotLighter[963:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (Barcode LIKE[c] 1123)'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x01783be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018d85c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
        2   CoreData                            0x00fe4676 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 1270
        3   CoreData                            0x00f1ca78 -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 488
        4   CoreData                            0x00f1c881 -[NSSQLAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:] + 49
        5   CoreData                            0x00f1c72e -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 430
        6   CoreData                            0x00f1bab5 -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 357
        7   CoreData                            0x00f1b66e -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 206
        8   CoreData                            0x00fcb0ec -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1084
        9   CoreData                            0x00f18807 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 359
        10  SpotLighter                         0x0000ff26 -[EntityCommands FetchManagedObject::] + 310
        11  SpotLighter                         0x0001436e -[WebAttendeeController FindAttendeeBy:] + 300
        12  SpotLighter                         0x0009aac6 -[MapBadge Map:::] + 4673
        13  SpotLighter                         0x000687d7 -[SpotLighterHomeScreen SpotLighterDataReceived::::] + 1111
        14  SpotLighter                         0x0002ca83 -[SpotlighterViewController txtNumericBadgeFieldDone:] + 445
        15  UIKit                               0x0051da6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        16  UIKit                               0x005ac1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
        17  UIKit                               0x005ae647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
        18  UIKit                               0x005ad1f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
        19  UIKit                               0x007a8987 _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 3609
        20  UIKit                               0x007a90fc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 927
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x01764fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x016fa0e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x016c2bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x016c2240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x016c2161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        26  GraphicsServices                    0x01f07268 GSEventRunModal + 217
        27  GraphicsServices                    0x01f0732d GSEventRun + 115
        28  UIKit                               0x0052c42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
        29  SpotLighter                         0x00002168 main + 102
        30  SpotLighter                         0x000020f9 start + 53
    )
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code to find where it is crashing and to check the values of the variables you are passing through? What else have you checked? Read the documentation? Checked Apple's examples to compare what they are doing with what you are doing?

Comment: ok thanks. i'll check and let you know the exact line where the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    return (WebAttendee *)[self FetchManagedObject:@"WebAttendee" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@ "Barcode LIKE [c] %@",badgeID_ ]];
```

was giving error...

I replaced the above line with

```
return (WebAttendee *)[self FetchManagedObject:@"WebAttendee" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@ "Barcode LIKE [c] '%@'",badgeID_ ]];
```

and it worked fine!